# Zf2 e "doctrine-module" retornam erro: No Metadata Classes to process

Tags: php, zend, doctrine, doctrine-2, zend-framework-2

Estou com problema quando vou executar o seguinte comando no terminal:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --filter="Category" --from-database annotation --namespace="Categoria\\Entity\\" module/Categoria/src
```

Aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> No Metadata Classes to process.

**Link do projeto** https://github.com/thuramlucas/testezend2.git

Comment: Qual mensagem? Lucas por favor, faça titulos que sejam intuitivos. Titulos com ajuda, help, please, por favor, blablabla, são redundantes, pois todos que vem aqui perguntar já estão procurando ajuda. Tenho certeza que vai levar meu comentário como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: No Metadata Classes to process.

Comment: Eu não entendo de doctrine, mas coloque no corpo da pergunta o conteudo de `module.config.php`.

Comment: Explique como clonar o projeto e reproduzir o erro, para que possamos ajudar.